# Question for repair

Tags: honda

Good day
I'm having a problem with my car it's has a hard started, according to the system it's says the sensor. I need to know what are those sensor and I must look for machenica or a electricians?

Comment: According to which system? If it is a code reader, then it will give the code and, some actually say the name of the sensor or a short description of the problem. So, do you have the code? What is the Make / Model / Year / Engine of the car as without that you won't get much. Do note that you question may well get closed as it does not have sufficient information.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you. Please use the [edit] feature to add details about your car and what codes "the system" is giving.

Answer (score 0):

There are auto parts stores that will do a free reading of engine codes and tell you what the problem is. Some will also give you a printout with thee codes and what they mean. Advanced auto parts and o'reilly auto parts will read your engine codes for free.